# Ubuntu Server 11.04 update 404 errors

Tags: 11.04, server, updates, ssh

I am an ubuntu amateur trying to set up an ubuntu 11.04 server on a tower. I want to install things like ssh client/ server and gksudo on it but I get errors when trying to do so. I tried to update, but I get 404 errors. I have already tried to install fix404 but it seems there is no "app-add" command...
After many hours of failure, I turn to you, wise people of the internet. You are my last hope.
help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that Ubuntu Server `11.04` has already reached [end of life](http://www.ubuntu.com/server). This means that the repositories for `11.04` are already switched off. Therefore you get the error code `404` from the repository servers.

You can either use `12.04` which is a LTS (Long Term Support) Release which is supported until April 2017.

The other possibility is to use `13.04` which is the current release and supported until January 2014.

Comment: your answer is extremely helpful. Thank you very much.